# Wie übersetzt man "step up my ... game"?

Tags: english-to-german

Ich habe `I’m definitely going to step up my ab game` gelesen, wie übersetzt man es besser als mit `Ich werde meine Bauchmuskeln auf jeden Fall weiter verbessern`? Das Problem ist, daß es idiomatisch übersetzt wird, ich suche aber eine näher an der Quelle liegende Übersetzung.

- "Ich werde bestimmt mein Bauchmuskelspiel erhöhen" -> Nein
- "Ich werde bestimmt mein Spiel mit meinen Bauchmuskeln erhöhen" -> Nein
- "Ich werde bestimmt mit meinen Bauchmuskeln spielen, um sie zu erhöhen" -> Nein

Comment: „ab game” = offenbar „abdominal game”? Aber was ist denn das für ein Spiel bzw. was ist ein „Bauchmuskelspiel”? Auch im Englischen finde ich nicht viel zu „abdominal game” – sollte es also nicht eigentlich eher „abdominal training“ = Bauchmuskeltraining heißen?

Answer (score 10):

Wie schon in den anderen Antworten dargelegt, ist eine wörtliche Übersetzung schlecht möglich.

Ich würde als Übersetzung ein anderes Wortbild verwenden:

> Ich werde beim Bauchmuskeltraining einen Gang höher schalten.

Game = eigener Anspruch = Training

step up = intensivieren = einen Gang höher schalten

Answer (score 6):

Nicht zuletzt inspiriert durch BestGuess' Antwort, hier weitere mehr oder weniger idiomatische Lösungen:

> Ich werd' beim Bauchmuskeltraining einen Zahn [oder: Zacken] zulegen.
>
> Ich werd' beim Bauchmuskeltraining jetzt richtig Dampf geben [oder: machen].
>
> Ich werd' beim Bauchmuskeltraining jetzt richtig Gas geben.
>
> Ich werd' beim Bauchmuskeltraining jetzt einen zulegen.

(Dieses Beispiel ist recht nahe an "step up", denke ich. Ich vermute einmal naiv, "step up" kommt ursprünglich aus der Mechanik und dem Umgang mit Schaltgetrieben. Dann ist "einen zulegen" besonders passend, da auch hier ursprünglich vermutlich ein Gang im Getriebe gemeint ist.)

> Ich werd' beim Bauchmuskeltraining noch eins drauflegen.

(Hier vermute ich, laienhaft, eher das Bild eines Ofens und eines Holzscheits im Hintergrund)

Comment: Ergänzung zu deiner Anmerkung bzgl. "step up": Meinem Verständnis nach ist hier das Bild eines Schrittes gemeint, z.B. auf einer Stufe, die man steigt. Man hebt somit das "game" auf die nächste Stufe. Das kann natürlich die einer Gangschaltung sein (habe ich in meiner Antwort auch so übersetzt), aber es kann auch eine abstrakte Stufe sein, wie z.B. Qualität oder Ethik. Außerdem kann "step up" auch der Schritt nach vorn sein, mit dem man sich aus einer uniformen Reihe bereitmeldet.

Comment: @BestGuess  Ich verstehe deine Überlegung, aber ich meine du liegst (vermutlich) falsch: Da es "step up something" ist (also transitiver Gebrauch) ist unbedingt ein Akkusativobjekt mitzudenken (oder direktes Objekt), und mit deinem "step up on something" hast du ein anderes Verhältnis. Darum neige ich zur Vermutung, dass es bei "step up something" immer schon um Dinge ging, die man irgendwie hochschalten (einen Schritt höher stellen) kann. Ob es nun ein Getriebe ist oder die Gangart eines Pferdes, sei dahingestellt. (Bur Vermutung natürlich. Sobald ich einen Etymologen treffe, frage ich ihn.)

Comment: Wieso ist ein Akkusativobjekt unbedingt mitzudenken? siehe Filmtitel "Step up" - kein Akkusativobjekt. Themen sind Auftreten auf die Tanzfläche, Heraustreten aus der Maße, Aufsteigen im Sozialgefüge und Aufstehen für die eigenen Träume.

Comment: Genau! Alle deine Bespiele für "step up" beziehen sich auf Verwendung ohne direktes Objekt. "Step up something" hat aber eines, und du müsstest nach frühen Verwendungen des Worts suchen, bei denen das direkte Objekt nicht ein Getriebe (o.ä.) ist.

Answer (score 4):

Das Problem einer wörtlichen Übersetzung ist, dass "Spiel" hier eben nicht dasselbe bedeutet wie "game" im Englischen. Also wird eine wörtliche Übersetzung praktisch immer fehlschlagen.

Genauso ist es mit "to step up" - "erhöhen" ist keine passende deutsche Übersetzung (man kann kein Training "erhöhen").

Dein erster Versuch ist zu weit weg vom Original - dort ist davon die Rede, dass das *Training* der Bauchmuskeln gesteigert wird und nicht die *Bauchmuskulatur* - deine deutsche Übersetzung hat das falsche Objekt, dein deutscher Satz sagt etwas anderes als das englische Original und nimmt einen Erfolg des Trainings vorweg.

Man könnte "game" als "Arbeit" übersetzen und mit einem deutschen Satz wie

> Ich werde ganz bestimmt meine Bauchmuskelarbeit intensivieren
>
> Ich werde ganz bestimmt bei meiner Bauchmuskelarbeit noch einen drauflegen
>
> Ich werde ganz bestimmt meine Bauchmuskelarbeit noch steigern

annehmbar nahe am Original, aber trotzdem in verständlichem Deutsch ankommen.

Comment: Brrr. 'intensivieren', klingt so nach furchtbar selbstoptierter Beratertype. Wie wären wohl ein zwei Alternativen noch dazu?  BM-training verschärfen, … noch schöner aber "beim Bauchmuskeltraining zulegen" ;) ?

Comment: @LangLangC Ich find' nix böses an "intensivieren" (natürlich eher mit dem Hintergrund "Sportschau-Interview" als "Weizenbier-nach-Fitnessstudio-Besuch-Gespräch".) "verschärfen" geht davon aus, dass es schon "scharf" ist. Und "zulegen" mit "Bauch" macht bei mir ein falsches Bild an... Ich hab' trotzdem noch ein paar Möglichkeiten aufgenommen

Comment: Eben. Für beides. Das 'falsche' Bild ist ja schon im Original: 'game', bei so einer ernsten Sache! (Btw: legt man einen (sixpack) drauf, oder zwei, also übereinander,  hat man auch eine gesunde Figur.

Comment: Kleine Korrektur/Ergänzung: die hier vorliegende Phrase lautet tatsächlich "to step up one's game" (wie von Philipp in seiner inzwischen gelöschten Antwort richtig identifiziert).

Answer (score 2):

> Ich muß mal etwas für meine Bauchmuskeln tun.

oder

> Ich werde mal etwas für meine Bauchmuskeln tun.